# Node_modules cannot be created

Tags: node-modules

After running these 2 commands I still cant get node_modules folder

npm init -y
npm install

Why is it like that? I’m stuck here for 3 weeks. Please help

But when i download someone else project and run the same commands it creates node_modules folder.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5PjR.png)

Comment: Because you have no modules in your project. If you really **only** run those two commands and no other commands before or after those two then it is correct to have no node_modules folder - this is by design. If there are no modules installed npm will not create the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct and by design.

If you have no modules installed in your project then `npm` will not create a `node_modules` folder.

Since you have just started a project then no matter how many times you run `npm install` it will not create a `node_modules` folder.

Built-in node modules such as `fs` are not installed in the `node_modules` folder so if you are only using modules that comes with node and don't install any 3rd party dependencies you won't have a `node_modules` folder in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt two methods:

**Creating a New Folder and Installing Dependencies:**
Begin by creating a new folder and copying the package.json file into it.
Run the command npm i or npm i -g within this new folder to install the dependencies. This will ensure the dependencies are installed within this specific folder.
Installing Dependencies in the Current Directory:

**If you prefer not to create a new folder**, you can directly execute npm i -g in the current directory. This will attempt to install the dependencies globally or in the parent directory based on the default installation settings.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Express dependency, I was able to install the node_modules folder.

I am a complete beginner, and I'm trying to create an e-commerce website. How do we know what dependencies we need to create?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).